# How to recreate a "leaning" CSS interface?

Tags: css, skew

I want to create an interface of this style with HTML & CSS : https://i.pinimg.com/originals/df/1c/11/df1c11c2ec58fce1e8c226bf85ca3a60.jpg

So far, I've got an interface that looks like this : https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B6vhIXDIdMc/maxresdefault.jpg

Those are illustrating pictures, but as you can see, my interface is not leaning as the one in the image. It does not have that "interface-on-a-screen" aspect, that I would like to recreate via CSS.

I tried using skew, but to no avail.
Do you know how I could recreate this effect ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you use skew ? it would also be better to see your codes.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't add the codepen in the question, it is a bit long but 多一点点爱 answered it anyway

Answer (score 0):

The parameters can be adjusted by themselves.

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  perspective: 400px;

}

img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform,0.8s;
  transform-origin: center bottom;

}

img:hover{
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg) rotateZ(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/df/1c/11/df1c11c2ec58fce1e8c226bf85ca3a60.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, you helped me a lot with this semantic for the transform rotate, it made a lot of sense.

I also found out about the perspective property which helped me to give this look I was going for, but I struggled a bit with it, it is because perspective only applies to children, not to the element itself.

So I made another div wrapper, add the perspective on that and changed my children, and it works fine, thanks !
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/